# Remove Seconds from DateTime c#

Tags: c#, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a section of code that converts the unix timestamp value to a standard time, however it is returning hours, minutes, and seconds. I would like it to only return Hours and Minutes.

```
convertSunriseTime = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(currentSunriseTime).ToString();
convertSunsetTime = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(currentSunsetTime).ToString();

private static TimeSpan UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp)
{
    DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp);
    return dtDateTime.TimeOfDay;
}
```

and the moment the varibles `convertSunriseTime` and `convertSunsetTime` come back with seconds.

Comment: So you want the *precision* of the result to be restricted to minutes only? How would you want to handle rounding timestamps with a non-whole number of minutes ?

Comment: Well with hours as well. of in the format of HH:mm. I don't really mind it it is a minutes or two off.

Comment: I think you are confusing the value with formatting. We can tell you how to round the value to a whole number of minutes, but the TimeSpan still inherently have the same precision. Do you want to _format the value so that it only displays hours and minutes?_

Comment: Yes that exactly what I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to format your value to show hours and minutes. You can do this:

```
convertSunriseTime = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(currentSunriseTime).ToString("hh\\:mm");
```

Here, the parameter to the ToString() method specifies that you are only interested in getting the hours and minutes parts into the resulting `string`. This is called a [custom TimeSpan format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx). There is also a set of standard ones: [Standard TimeSpan format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

this can do the work:

```
private static TimeSpan UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp)
{
    DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp);
    dtDateTime = DateTime.FromMinutes((int)dtdateTime.TotalMinutes);
    return dtDateTime.TimeOfDay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you try this way
```

```
convertSunriseTime = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(currentSunriseTime).ToString();
```

```
convertSunsetTime = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(currentSunsetTime).ToString();
```

```
<pre>private static TimeSpan UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp) </pre>
<pre>{</pre>
        <pre>DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);</pre>
    <pre>dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp);</pre>
        <pre>return dtDateTime.TimeOfDay;</pre>
<pre>}</pre>
```